# Spinner replacing array adds new entries instead

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I have a spinner that I want to change the available items based on the program state. I use the arrayadapter class like below

`ArrayAdapter array;
array = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, Movements);
array.NotifyDataSetChanged();
spnMove.Adapter = array;`

but if I run through this code second time, It just adds the new lisr to the bottom instead of replacing it.

I've already tried setting the .Adapter reference to NULL before adding the new array, but this made precisely no difference at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a new ArrayAdapter for a new dataset, try just updating the data. First call the `clear()` method on the adapter to delete all old data. Then call `add()` or `addAll()` on the ArrayAdapter to add the new data. Finally call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to make sure the list is notified.

Comment: This in correct and helped to solve the problem, but what kept me from finding it myself was a me forgetting to clear the base list that my array adapter was derived from.